# Django AllAuth redirecting to signin for for First and Last name despite not required

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using Django AllAuth and trying to let people instantly log in with Discord.

When they do that, it takes them to a signup form that forces them to enter their First and Last Name.  These are not required fields in my user model so I have no idea why this would be forced.

Here are my settings:

```
# Authentication - Using AllAuth
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = False
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 180
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 360
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/account/logout/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {}
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = False
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True`?

Comment: @R.Uziel it's True by default, but added it just in case and still having same issue 